# React/Node error sending data to MySQL database

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a complicated problem with my Node/React app. I have a shopping cart with the final element when checking out is to add order details to my MySQL database, however my function is returning an error from the controller. I am posting the relevant code, the full code is too extensive for a post.

This is the Node route:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var controller = require('../controllers/controller');

  // controller Routes
  app.route('/products')
    .get(controller.list_all_products)
    .post(controller.create_a_product);
    app.route('/products/:product_type')
    .get(controller.products_by_type);
   app.route('/product/:productId')
    .get(controller.read_a_product)
    .put(controller.update_a_product)
    .delete(controller.delete_a_product);
};
```

This is the relevant part of the controller:

```
exports.create_a_product = function(req, res) {
  var new_product = new Product(req.body);

  //handles null error 
   if(!new_product.product || !new_product.status){
        res.status(400).send({ error:true, message: 'Please provide product/status' });
    } else {
  Product.createProduct(new_product, function(err, product) {
    
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(product);
  });
}
};
```

The relevant part of the Model:

```
var Product = function(product){
    this.product = product.product;
    this.status = Product.status;
    this.created_at = new Date();
};
Product.createProduct = function (newProduct, result) {    
    sql.query("INSERT INTO orders set ?", newProduct, function (err, res) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("error: ", err);
            result(err, null);
        }
        else{
            console.log(res.insertId);
            result(null, res.insertId);
        }
    });           
};
```

Then the React side uses this api call:

```
import $ from 'jquery'

export const addOrder = order => {
    const urlString = "http://localhost:9000/products"
    return $.ajax({
        url: urlString,
        method: "POST",
        data: order,
        success: () => {
            console.log('order logged')
        },
        error: (status, err) => {
            console.log(status)
        }
    })
  }
```

And finally I make the call with this var:

```
 var r = await addOrder(this.state.order).then(res => res.json())
```

The order details are a simple object:

```
this.state = {
            order: {
                oid: '',
                order_date: '',
                products: '',
                first_name: '',
                last_name: '',
                email: '',
                address: '',
                city: '',
                province: '',
                zip: '',
                country: ''
            }
        }
```

When executing I get the error 'Please provide product/status' from the controller.

I know this is a tough one, any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: The `order` object you send to the `products` endpoint neither does have a `status` nor a `product` property. Thus the error. Are you really supposed to send an `order`  object to the `products` endpoint? Shouldn't this be an `orders` endpoint? Or a `product` object?

Comment: I have kind of repurposed the create product function to work for orders, I guess this is were the problem is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you send the order object to products service which may contain multiple products. You should extract products from the order object (req.body) and send them to createProduct method in a loop.